# If statement not working in side def in class

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement, methods

So i am working with classes and if statements. When the if statement is inside the class def, it seems to be ignored and not sure what i am doing wrong. I want it to raise an exception if the criteria is not met.

I tried to change name to __name but that did not seem to help. I also tried to remove def get_name(self) to see if that caused the problem but it did not.

```
class Strict:
    name:str

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


    def set_name(self,name):
        if len(name) != 5:
            raise Exception("Name must be exactly 5 characters")

        else:
            return name




try:
    z = Strict("ABCDEFGH")
    print(z.name)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Comment: Currently it prints out ABCDEFGH

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You never call the `set_name` function inside or outside of your class. If you want to check the name on the initialization of your class, you can call that function in your `__init__` function like this:

```
class Strict:
    name:str

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = self.set_name(name)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name


    def set_name(self,name):
        if len(name) != 5:
            raise Exception("Name must be exactly 5 characters")

        else:
            return name




try:
    z = Strict("ABCDEFGH")
    print(z.name)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

The pythonic way of using setters and getters is rather different. You could use the following code:

```
class Strict:
name:str

def __init__(self,name):
    self.name = name

@property
def name(self):
    return self._name

@name.setter
def name(self,name):
    if len(name) != 5:
        raise Exception("Name must be exactly 5 characters")

    else:
        self._name = name
```